# How to place Unity .so libraries in the Managed directory during build

Tags: android, linux, unity-game-engine

I am using a library (`GRPC`) in Unity which requires that the `.so` library be located in the `/Managed` directory. If I put the `libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so` file into the `Assets/Plugins/` folder for my Unity project, it is copied into the `/Plugins` directory during the build.

For example: the linux build will place the library in `[app_name]_Data/Plugins/x86_64/`. If I simply move the file into `[app_name]_Data/Managed/`, everything works. Unfortunately, while this "post-build moving" is viable on Linux, it's much more difficult on Android (which would require unzipping the APK and re-signing).

Is there any way to make Unity place the library directly into the `/Managed` folder?

Comment: Is it a C++ library? I noticed you tagged Android and Linux. Which one are you targeting?

Comment: I am targeting all mobile & desktop platforms; I've solved iOS already, and Linux works via the strategy described, but I'm trying to find a solution that works better for Linux + Android. GRPC is built in C++, yes, and compiled into the `*.so` file I describe. See the open-source repository at: https://github.com/grpc/grpc

Comment: Ok. Why is it required that the library be located in the /Managed directory? Where are you currently placing it for the Android in the Editor?

Comment: Because the GRPC library looks in the `/Managed` directory to load the `.so` file at runtime (see the `Load()` function in `NativeExtensions.cs` in the git project I linked you to). I'd prefer not to fork the official Google library for obvious reasons. The editor doesn't actually load platform code, but per my original question, I'm placing the `.so` file in `Assets/Plugins/`. I've also tried `Assets/Plugins/Android/`.

Comment: FWIW, the `.so` file makes its way into the `APK` at `/lib/armeabi-v7a/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.so` (as it is copied by Unity). But GRPC cannot find it amongst the paths it searches: ```No dynamic GRPC library at: /data/app/com.MoongateInteractive.Moongate-1/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.so, /data/app/com.MoongateInteractive.Moongate-1/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/runtimes/linux/native/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.so, /data/app/com.MoongateInteractive.Moongate-1/base.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/../../runtimes/linux/native/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.so```

Comment: For my case, it worked when I placed the `libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so` file in `Assets` without the `.x64` part